# Getting "Unsupported block type" error wile creating aws EKS cluster with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to create an EKS cluster with terrafor using this documentation -
[terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_cluster.html#eks-cluster-with-access-config)
I check "EKS Cluster with Access Config" section and add access_config, but when I run terraform plan command I am getting next error:

> on eks.tf line 144, in resource "aws_eks_cluster" "aws_eks": 144: access_config {
> Blocks of type "access_config" are not expected here.

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "aws_eks" {
  name     = var.eks_cluster_name
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster.arn

  enabled_cluster_log_types = ["api", "audit", "authenticator"]
  
  vpc_config {
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access  = false
    
    subnet_ids = [
      aws_subnet.eks_public_subnet[0].id,
      aws_subnet.eks_public_subnet[1].id,
      aws_subnet.eks_private_subnet[0].id,
      aws_subnet.eks_private_subnet[1].id
    ]
  }
  
  access_config {
    authentication_mode                         = "API"
    bootstrap_cluster_creator_admin_permissions = true
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSClusterPolicy,
    aws_cloudwatch_log_group.eks_logs  
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which provider version are you on?

Comment: my aws provider's version = ">= 4.0"

Comment: That just says you can use any provider version higher than 4.x.x, but it doesn't tell me which version you are currently on.

Comment: Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v5.31.0

Comment: Try upgrading to 5.35.0, not sure when that part of the configuration was introduced, but it's not there in [5.31.0](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/5.31.0/docs/resources/eks_cluster).

Comment: Ok thank you will have a look.

Comment: @MarkoE changing aws provider version helped me to resolved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

setting aws provider version to >=5.35 as [Marko E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8343484/marko-e) suggests solved this problem for me